Using shapely from Python script tool in ArcPy with ArcMap
I have received a geoprocessing tool which references a python script. The script uses some methods from the shapely library.
I have tried putting the shapely library (version 1.6.0) directory and files in the following directory:
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\Lib\site-packages

but I get the following error message:
error 193 (%1 is not a valid Win32 app)

I have also tried installing shapely 1.6.0 using pip in the arcgis folder as follows:
Python27\ArcGIS10.8\Scripts\pip.bat install shapely==1.6.0

and get the same error.
So how can I get shapely to work with ArcGIS 10.8?

I would have definitely installed shapely into the python environment using pip. Be aware that shapely 2x had some breaking changes in the way it accesses geometries so version 1.6.0 is quite old now.
